# How to filter a field in the add content window in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am very new to Drupal so I'm sorry for my lack of familiarity with Drupal terminology.

I have a content type with multiple fields (A, B, C, etc..). Each field is a selectable vocabulary list. I would like the user to select any terms in A and B fields. But I want only relevant terms to display in the C field (depending on A and B selections). In this way, A and B are independent fields and terms that appear in C are dependent.

**Example:**

Content type: Food dish at a restaurant

Field A: Appears on Menu type (Breakfast menu, lunch menu, dinner menu, wine list,etc.)

Field C: Appear in Menu section (Appetizers, Entrees, Deserts, etc.)

If the user selects "Breakfast Menu" for field A, it wouldn't make much sense to allow the user to select "Desert" for field C. But selecting "Appetizers" or "Entrees" would be fine. I want to filter the selectable terms in field C depending on which options are selected for field A.

Thank you for helping me out! Really :)

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution is to use [Simple hierarchical select](https://drupal.org/project/shs) or [Hierarchical Select](https://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select). But in this case, you will have to combine all your terms inside one taxonomy vocabulary taking advantage of taxonomy's parent-child relationship. And [Hierarchical Select](https://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) will take care of the rest.

[Hierarchical Select Documentation](https://drupal.org/node/262835).